# Minimal Connections to Program Renesas RE01

Tags: renesas

I'm trying to program a [R7F0E01182DNG#AA0](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/re-cortex-m-ultra-low-power-sotb-mcus/re01-256kb-705-ulpmark-cp-score-global-top-class-ultra-low-power-mcu-based-sotb-process-technology) MCU, using the serial programming feature. It's not working, so as part of troubleshooting I'm paring my design down to the minimum functional circuit. This is what I have:

[image: minimal schematic]

Can someone familiar with these chips tell me if it looks correct?

Power is supplied from a bench PSU, and the programmer is a 3.3v USB to serial adapter. The DTS line on the serial adaper is used as a reset signal and I confirmed that that is working with a logic analyzer.

Secondary question: if I wanted to program it using SWD, which pins are those? I can't find it in the datasheet or manual.

**Edit:**

I determined the SWD pins. SWCLK is TXD9 (P411). SWDIO is RXD9 (P207).

I also obtained an official programmer, the e2 lite. And it still does not work.. When I use that I get the error message "Error 0x00040102: Not connected to the user system." And I checked with an logic analyzer and it's not toggling any pins before the error occurs... ugh

Comment: Normally microcontrollers have a cap on the reset pin and they are quite picky with the value chosen. Is this not the case here? What does the datasheet say?

Comment: @Lundin According to the hardware design guide (page 23), no cap is required.

Comment: Ok but regardless of that, exposing the reset pin to a connector and a long trace is somewhat naive. This is not a signal that you want to expose to EMI. So if the MCU doesn't want a cap there for reset timing purposes, then at least add some 47pF to 100pF for EMI reasons.

Comment: @Lundin I'm just trying to get the chip to program, at all. I'm not really at that phase of the design yet.

Comment: I would probably drop this serial bootloader thing then and use SWD. You'll want SWD for debugging no matter.

Comment: I was thinking that too. I was actually going to try the e2 lite programmer because it's officially supported and reasonably priced. Do you think I should go for a generic SWD programmer instead? I have a st link v2.

Comment: From what I hear ST link only works on ST. I'd recommend a Segger JLink, I'm using one for some 4-5 different Cortex M projects, all with different MCU vendors. Microchip, ST, NXP, Silabs...